# this->operator=() not working

Tags: c++, class, operators, runtime-error

Hi Im making a game in c++ using directX

but I have a console version of the game as well (using 'X's and other characters to represent things)

I have the following code:

```
Unit::Unit(UnitType u){
    ZeroAll();                        // function that zeros all variables
    this->operator=(fileToUnit(u));   // error making code
}
```

UnitType is a simple enumerated data type with three values {Infantry , Alien , Predator}.

the Operator function is defined as follows

```
Unit operator= (Unit u) { return u; }
```

fileToUnit is...

```
Unit fileToUnit(UnitType u);
```

just makes a temporary Unit and returns it. I really don't know how else to do it but I need to change the whole class from in the constructor.

edit:
 sorry for being so unspecific

my question is:
 how to make a class change its values based on the results of a function

like

```
this = functionReturningSameDataType( DataType ConstructorParameters );
```

the error is as follows

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP110D.dll
File: C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring
Line: 1143

Expression: invalid null pointer

For Information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to Debug the application)
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Do you have an error to show us?

Comment: In what possible case would an `operator=` do that? Also, I would recommend starting to learn to pass by reference when possible.

Comment: Why you don't try `*this = fileToUnit(u);` ?

Comment: no return type for `operator=`?

Comment: @icepack, not only no return type, but if it is really as described then no assignment either.

Comment: Post some more code. What you've posted makes very little sense.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MM. I tried that and it didn't work. thanks for the help tho.

Comment: What does `ZeroAll()` look like? Is `this` a part of `All`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a *free function* which takes a `UnitType` as an argument, constructs a `Unit` in some way which is presumably based on the `UnitType` instance, then returns this to the constructor `Unit::Unit(UnitType)`.

I'm not sure I fully understand the purpose of `Unit fileToUnit(UnitType u)` in this context. Why is it a free function? Make it a member function and call it from your constructor:

```
class Unit
{
private:
   // Example data members
   int foo;
   int bar;
public:
   Unit(UnitType u)
   {
      fileToUnit(UnitType u);
   };
private:
   void fileToUnit(UnitType u)
   {
       // Set data members here
       foo = 1;
       bar = 1;
   };
};
```

EDIT: In such a simplified example as mine, `fileToUnit` doesn't need to exist at all, and the code should go directly in the constructor:

```
class Unit
{
private:
   // Example data members
   int foo;
   int bar;
public:
   Unit(UnitType u)
   {
      // Set foo and bar here, using whatever
      // information you need from u
   };
};
```

Comment: `fileToUnit()` is there because all the information for the Unit is held in separate files but thanks I wasn't thinking (on hour 9 of programming)